# Remove excessive lists in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, recursion

I have a dictionary consisting of nested lists and dictionaries. Some of those lists consist only of one element: another list. I want to keep the element, but I want to remove the meaningless one-elemented list. E.g. from

```
  {'geojson': [{'geometry': {'coordinates': [[[5., 52.],
                                             [5., 52.],
                                             [5., 52.],
 ]],
                            'type': 'Polygon'},
               'properties': {},
               'type': 'Feature'}]},
```

I want to have

```
  {'geojson': {'geometry': {'coordinates': [[5., 52.],
                                             [5., 52.],
                                             [5., 52.],
 ],
                            'type': 'Polygon'},
               'properties': {},
               'type': 'Feature'}},
```

I tried a recursive function. It recognizes the pieces correctly, but it returns my argument unaltered.

```
def eliminate_excessive_nested_lists(x):

    if isinstance(x,list):
        if len(x) == 1:
            x = x[0]  #I tried x[:] = x[0] but it works neither 
            eliminate_excessive_nested_lists(x)
        else:
            for element in x:
                eliminate_excessive_nested_lists(element)
    elif isinstance(x,dict):
        for key in x.keys():   
            eliminate_excessive_nested_lists(x[key])
    return x
```

How can I make the line
x = x[0]
actually work? (or find an entirely different approach)

Comment: It doesn't need to be recursive and an iterative version will avoid the excessive call overhead. I believe the problem is that x is a copied scope variable. You probably need to be returning the eleminate_excessive_nested_lists() to actually pass the values throug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I have tried to fix your function with minimum changes as possible. Hope this helps:

```
def eliminate_excessive_nested_lists(x):

    if isinstance(x,list):
        # Case 1: If x itself is list and is nested with 1 element
        # unpack and call the function again
        if len(x) == 1:
            x = x[0]
            eliminate_excessive_nested_lists(x)
        else:
            # Case 2: if list has multiple elements
            # call the function indivually on each element and store in a 
            # seperate list. Copy the new list to old list
            # Note: Previously you were setting x = eliminate(element)
            # which was wrong since you were storing x as unpacked version of 
            # the elements
            temp_list = []
            for element in x:
                temp_list.append(eliminate_excessive_nested_lists(element))
            x = temp_list
    elif isinstance(x,dict):
        # Case 3: If x is dictionary, then for each key, set it's value to
        # x[key] = eliminate(x[key])
        # Note: previously you were setting this as x = eliminate(x[key])
        # which was wrong since you were setting x as unpacked version of x[key]
        for key in x.keys():
            x[key] = eliminate_excessive_nested_lists(x[key])

    return x
```

[Link to Google Colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1EHXym8o4gKfKlp8B1IOMd67exGnipXs_) with working code and test.